# Listbox not displaying in UserForm

Tags: vba, listbox

I'm trying to display a listbox in a UserForm from a separate sheet called "Fields". The problem is, the list will not display. It shows as a drop down arrow next to the cell, but not in the userform like I'm wanting.

```
  Private Sub UserForm_Activate2()
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.ListBox2.Clear
    For Each element In gFieldsListArr
        Me.ListBox2.AddItem element
    Next element
    UserForm_initialize2
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_initialize2()
    For Each element In Split(gCellCurrVal2, ",")
        For ii = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
            If element = Me.ListBox2.List(ii) Then
                Me.ListBox2.Selected(ii) = True
            End If
        Next ii
    Next element
End Sub
```

Comment: Why `On Error Resume Next`? Are you swallowing any errors?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: You can't rename event handlers or change their member signature in any way*, because the correct member definition is defined by the event, not its handlers.

---

Watch the dropdowns at the top of the editor as you navigate between procedure scopes:

[image: left dropdown says "(General)"]

Whenever the left-side dropdown says `(General)`, you're not inside an event handler.

Contrast with:

[image: left dropdown says "UserForm"]

The left-side dropdown is listing all available interfaces and event sources; to handle the events of a form, you must pick `UserForm` from that dropdown, and then pick a member from the right-side dropdown.

When you do this, the VBE creates the procedure stubs for you, *with the correct name and signature every time*.

Whenever you navigate to what's intended to be an event handler and the left-side dropdown says `(General)`, you're looking at dead code that isn't responding to any events.

---

* You may change the accessibility from `Private` to `Public`, but invoking an event handler directly is a design smell so there shouldn't be a need to do that. You may change the parameter *names*, but not their *type*; renaming handler parameters is a rather surprising thing to do though, and best avoided too. So yeah, best not change these member signatures in any way.